# Angularjs Controller in Coffeescript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, ionic-framework

I'm an Angularjs newbie and I'm trying to create a settings panel in Ionic Framework. I want to save the setting into localStorage, but for now I'm just logging the scope change. But it doesn't work and I'm getting crazy.

My HTML is

```
<ion-view title="Settings">
  <ion-content class="has-header">

    <ul class="list" ng-controller="settingsController as setting">
        <ion-toggle ng-model="setting.examType.checked"
                    ng-change="setting.examTypeChange()"
                    ng-true-value="oltre"
                    ng-false-value="entro">
        Exam Type
        </ion-toggle>
    </ul>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and my controller is

```
class Settings extends Controller
  constructor: ($localStorage) ->

    @examType = { checked: 'entro' }

    @examTypeChange = () ->
      console.log('exam type change', @examType.checked)
      return
```

I'm using ng-classify, compiled in javascript the result is:

function() {
  var Settings;

```
  Settings = (function() {
    function Settings($localStorage) {

      this.examType = {
        checked: 'entro'
      };
      this.examTypeChange = function() {
        console.log('exam type change', this.examType.checked);
      };
    }

    return Settings;

  }
```

Log doesn't work: when I switch toggle nothing happen.
Any idea?